# Macro pasting start row 4 not 1, headers, and sum total

Tags: excel, vba

I have this great macro that creates my sheet and copies and paste information starting in "A1" but I need it to paste starting in "A4" of the new sheet.  I plan to add headings in row 1  and totals in row 3. So if you could point me in the right direction to figure that out too it would be great.  The amount of rows will vary for the totals.

```
Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

   With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
   End With


    'Delete the sheet "SUMMARY" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SUMMARY").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

   'Add a worksheet with the name "SUMMARY"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "SUMMARY"

    'Move the worksheet "SUMMARY"
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Select
    Sheets("SUMMARY").Move Before:=Sheets(7)


    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sh.Name, _
    Array(DestSh.Name, "EnGarde Data", "Service                                     Data", "Usage", "TECHNICIAN", "MASTER", "Dropdown lists"), 0)) Then


           'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("F2")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
               MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'Copy range to new sheet
            CopyRng.Copy DestSh.cells(Last + 1, "B")

            'Copy the sheet name in the A column
            DestSh.cells(Last + 1, "A").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B6")

           'Copy range to new sheet
           CopyRng.Copy DestSh.cells(Last + 1, "C")

           'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("B4")

           'Copy range to new sheet
           CopyRng.Copy DestSh.cells(Last + 1, "D")

       End If
   Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.GoTo DestSh.cells(1)

'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing DestSh.cells(Last + 1, "A") to DestSh.Range("A4:A" & rows.count) = CopyRng

Comment: That makes it take the first "F2" it copies and then paste it until it runs out of space on the SUMMARY sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your macro completed, and all info pasted starting from "A1", you can simply insert the rows before first one. So add this line after `ExitTheSub:` as many times as as you want blank lines:

```
DestSh.Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```